# How do I decompose a URL into its component parts in Java?

Tags: java

My requirements are fairly simple, but I need to do a lot of this so I'm looking for a robust solution.

Is there a good light-weight library for decomposing URLs into their component parts in Java?  I'm referring to hostname, query string, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [java.net.URL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html).  It has methods for exactly what you're trying to do.

Hostname: `getHost()`
Query string: `getQuery()`
Fragment/ref/anchor: `getRef()`
Path: `getPath()`

Answer (score 22):

I am always forgetting the URI format, so here it is:

```
<scheme>://<userinfo>@<host>:<port><path>#<fragement>
```

And here an example:

```
URI uri = new URI ("query://jeff@books.com:9000/public/manuals/appliances?stove#ge");
```

The following will happen:

- `uri.getAuthority()` will return `"jeff@books.com:9000"`
- `uri.getFragment ()` will return `"ge"`
- `uri.getHost ()` will return `"books.com"`
- `uri.getPath ()` will return `"/public/manuals/appliances"`
- `uri.getPort ()` will return `9000`
- `uri.getQuery ()` will return `"stove"`
- `uri.getScheme ()` will return `"query"`
- `uri.getSchemeSpecificPart ()` will return `"//jeff@books.com:9000/public/manuals/appliances?stove"`
- `uri.getUserInfo ()` will return `"jeff"`
- `uri.isAbsolute ()` will return `true`
- `uri.isOpaque ()` will return `false`

I found this blog handy: [Exploring Java's Network API: URIs and URLs](http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=26566&seqNum=3)

Answer (score 5):

`java.net.URI` and `java.net.URL` do not work for many modern URLs. `java.net.URI` adheres to RFC 2396, which a really old standard. `java.net.URL` sometimes does a good job, but if you're working with URLs as found in the wild, it will fail for many cases.

In order to solve these issues, I wrote [galimatias](https://github.com/smola/galimatias), a URL parsing and normalization library for Java. It will work with almost any URL you can imagine (basically, if it works in a web browser, galimatias will parse it correctly). And it has very convenient API.

You can get it at: https://github.com/smola/galimatias

Answer (score 0):

Look at the getter methods of the [URL class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html).

You have all you need there.

Answer (score 0):

```
URL.getProtocol()
URL.getHost()
URL.getPort()
```

And so on.